# Recursive query to join the result set with the table as long as there are more matches

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion

```
CUSTOMER
customer_id | email1 | email2 | phone1 | phone2

REGISTRATION
registration_id | email3 | ip

REGISTRATION_TO_CUSTOMER
registration_id | customer_id | email4

BANNED
banned_id   | ip | email | phone
```

DATA SAMPLE:

```
CUSTOMER 
1 | test1_1@mail.com  | test1_2@mail.com | 1 | 11|
2 | test2_1@mail.com  | test2_2@mail.com | 2 | 1 |
3 | test3_1@mail.com  | test3_2@mail.com | 3 | 33|

REGISTRATION
1 | test1_1a@mail.com | 192.168.1.1
2 | test2_1a@mail.com | 192.168.1.3
3 | test3_1a@mail.com | 192.168.1.3

REGISTRATION_TO_CUSTOMER
1 | 1 | test1_1a@mail.com 
2 | 2 | test2_1b@mail.com 
3 | 3 | test3_1c@mail.com 

BANNED
1 | 192.168.1.3 | null           | null
3 | null        | test2@mail.com | null
```

**Explanation:**

- BANNED has 2 records, but I have 3 customers
- Query to match banned and customer will return 2 customers with ID#2 and ID#3 because they have matching data in Banned table.
- **QUESTION**: Customer #3 has the same phone as Customer#1; therefore **Customer #1** also needs to be listed. Therefore, I need to join the ResultSet with BANNED recursively (as many times as needed) to re-query the database and get the complete list of all possible linked customers

So I tried this (and it returns no results whatsoever):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT customer_id,
    email1,
    email2,
    email3,
    email4,
    phone1,
    phone2,
    ip
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT r.ip,
            r.registration_id,
            r.email3,
            rc.email4,
            c.customer_id,
            c.email1,
            c.email2,
            c.phone1,
            c.phone2
        FROM (
            SELECT registration_id,
                email3,
                ip
            FROM REGISTRATION
            ) r
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT registration_id,
                customer_id,
                email4
            FROM REGISTRATION_TO_CUSTOMER
            ) rc
            ON r.registration_id = rc.registration_id
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT customer_id,
                email1,
                email2,
                phone1,
                phone2
            FROM CUSTOMER
            ) c
            ON rc.customer_id = c.customer_id
        ) start WITH (
            email1,
            email2,
            email3,
            email4,
            phone1,
            phone2,
            ip
            ) IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT CUST.email1,
                CUST.email2,
                CUST.email3,
                CUST.email4,
                CUST.phone1,
                CUST.phone2,
                CUST.ip
            FROM (
                SELECT r.ip,
                    r.registration_id,
                    r.email3,
                    rc.email4,
                    c.customer_id,
                    c.email1,
                    c.email2,
                    c.phone1,
                    c.phone2
                FROM (
                    SELECT registration_id,
                        email3,
                        ip
                    FROM REGISTRATION
                    ) r
                INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT registration_id,
                        customer_id,
                        email4
                    FROM REGISTRATION_TO_CUSTOMER
                    ) rc
                    ON r.registration_id = rc.registration_id
                INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT customer_id,
                        email1,
                        email2,
                        phone1,
                        phone2
                    FROM CUSTOMER
                    ) c
                    ON rc.customer_id = c.customer_id
                ) CUST
            INNER JOIN BANNED
                ON CUST.ip = BANNED.ip
                    OR CUST.email1 = BANNED.email
                    OR CUST.email2 = BANNED.email
                    OR CUST.email3 = BANNED.email
                    OR CUST.email4 = BANNED.email
                    OR CUST.phone1 = BANNED.phone
                    OR CUST.phone2 = BANNED.phone
            ) connect BY nocycle email1 = prior email1
        OR email2 = prior email2
        OR email3 = prior email3
        OR email4 = prior email4
        OR phone1 = prior phone1
        OR phone2 = prior phone2
        OR ip = prior ip
    )
ORDER BY customer_id
```

Comment: Since you are using Oracle, you can probably do this via an "[Hierarchical Query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)".

Comment: Is the banned ID actually related to customer ID, or they they independent synthetic keys on their respective tables? What final output do you want - all disintct IPs, emails and phone numbers, or complete customer records?

Comment: PKs are surrogate, auto-increments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query looks promising:

```
select distinct id, ip, email, phone
  from (
    select id, ip, email, phone, 
      from customer start with 
        (ip, email, phone) in (
          select distinct c.ip, c.email, c.phone
            from customer c join banned b 
              on b.ip = c.ip or b.email = c.email or b.phone = c.phone)
      connect by nocycle ip = prior ip or email = prior email or phone = prior phone)
  order by id
```

Here is [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/66234/5).

---

Edit: The modified query taking into account new tables, added in question: `registration, registration_to_customer` and additional phones and emails.

```
with cust as (
  select customer_id cid, registration_id rid, ip, phone1, phone2, 
      email1, email2, email3, email4
    from registration r
      join registration_to_customer rc using (registration_id)
      join customer using (customer_id))
select distinct cid, rid, ip, phone1, phone2, email1, email2, email3, email4
  from cust
  start with (ip, phone1, phone2, email1, email2, email3, email4)
    in (
      select b.ip, phone1, phone2, email1, email2, email3, email4 from cust
        join banned b on b.ip = cust.ip
          or b.email in (cust.email1, cust.email2, cust.email3, cust.email4)
          or b.phone in (cust.phone1, cust.phone2))
  connect by nocycle 
    email1 in (prior email1, prior email2, prior email3, prior email4) or
    email2 in (prior email1, prior email2, prior email3, prior email4) or
    email3 in (prior email1, prior email2, prior email3, prior email4) or
    email4 in (prior email1, prior email2, prior email3, prior email4) or
    phone1 in (prior phone1, prior phone2) or
    phone2 in (prior phone1, prior phone2) or
    ip = prior ip
  order by cid
```

Comment: I actually trying to use your example, but my query returns no results... Any ideas why?

Comment: You modified data structure compared to the original question. Added fields email2 and phone2 and two new tables? I'll try to discern in your new query, please check again for some time.

Comment: New query in answer. Operators `sys_connect_by_path` and `connect_by_root` may be useful to find the original banned. Do not ban me ;-)

Comment: One more note: your actual query gives me two rows with current examples and you wrote that there are no results. Weird, maybe you changed something in your data? Anyway - I think that in your query you didn't compare ALL phones and ALL emails with each other.

Comment: I actually made an wrong assumption about my query being wrong. I actually got it right (as you mentioned needed to compare ALL data with each other). The problem that I have is that my server runs of memory.

Comment: Do you have any ideas how to optimize it? My select on 3 tables takes  30 minutes to render and produces around 1 mil of records :\

Comment: I was afraid that such hierarchical query will not be the rocket on big tables :-/
As for optimize - it's hard to say something for sure without data access. Can you specify approximate number of rows in each table?
My quick ideas are: 1) proper indexes, 2) checking only newest banned and newest users, 3) procedure in PL SQL, but it has to work in similar way, so I doubt it would be faster 4) gathering data about suspicious in some other table.
You can also form new question, probably other users have some interesting ideas.

Comment: I was thinking about #2 - new users only; BUT I don't think this is even possible. We select FROM ALL users and looking for those who as IN matches. Therefore we need to select all, because 1 new user might bring the chain of users which have been around for a while in dormant state but not associated with banned yet.

Comment: Let's say Bob logs in. We check his data in `suspicious` table. He is clear, so no further action. Now Joe logs in. We find his email in one of previous suspicious, so we run our query starting ONLY with Joe's data and put all found chained rows into suspicious. What do you think?

Comment: OK; But the very first CLASUE checks is Bob, or Joe, or anyone else are IN suspicious table, right? Therefore if they are not IN there, they won't be shown. Therefore if we won't select all of them, how do we check if they are IN somewhere when we did not select them in the first place? Unless I misunderstand something. I think that this scenario will catch the NEW accounts, but I won't show other accounts if new accounts are linking to old accounts which are already in the system

Comment: Yes we have first build table of suspicious historically analysing every login. Tedious and long but achievable. Second question is what to do when we add someone to banned.

Comment: So step by step: 1) we gather as many data from our query into table suspicious as your server can withstand, lets say it will be operating on first 10000 rows from `users` and all `banned` 2) every next historical login we analyze one by one adding new suspicious chains to table suspicious 3) new logins are analyzed up to date. (Sorry, my english is not the best.)